# Bash get hard drive path

Tags: bash, hard-drive

Is there a way to get the symbolic path (e.g. /dev/sda) of a computer's hard drive with a  bash script executed from a flash drive inserted into the computer? Is it always /dev/sda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be different from `sda`. what if the computer has 4 hard-drives?

You could run `fdisk -l` as root (or sudo), check the bootable Device. usually it would be the `C:` drive. But it doesn't mean that device contains windows.

One can install Windows on hard-disk(II) but boot from Disk(I).

So the `fdisk -l` way can help you find the bootable partition/Disk on that machine. You can check the FS if it **could** be windows system FS (e.g. FAT32/NTFS).  But it cannot tell you if that Disk has windows (those windows system files) installed.

Moreover, if the computer has 4 Disks, and install winOS on each of them, so there are 4 windows installed. say a multi-booting system. I cannot find a proper solution to find those disks except for mounting those partitions and checking FS.

Answer (score 0):

By "computer's hard drive" I assume you mean the root file system for which Linux is booted.  You can use the df utility to check what `/` was mounted to:

```
$ df / 
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             10317828   7824696   1969016  80% /
$ df / | grep / | cut -d" " -f1
/dev/sda1
$
```

`/dev/sda1` is simply the first partition of the drive `/dev/sda`.  In my case it is also `dev/sda`, but you certainly can't guarantee it will always be this.  You might see `/dev/hda` if it is an IDE disk.  `/dev/sda` is generally SATA or SCSI.  `/dev/sdb` would be the second disk on the system, and so on.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. If I insert a flash drive running Ubuntu into a computer and that computer has windows installed, I want the path to the hard drive containing windows.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood.  I was going to update my answer, but it looks like @Kent covered it fully in his answer.  So I'm upvoting his.